# Classify manifolds by maximal possible parametrization

Tags: general-topology, geometry

If you want to treat manifolds in the computer,  it is nice to have a continuous bijection between the manifold with the two or three dimensional Euclidian space.

Unfortunately, this is rarely possible, due to topological constraints. For example it is not possible for spheres,  tori, cylinders. However, those three examples differ in how badly they are impossible to parametrize with $ R^2$. For the sphere you have to leave one point out (e.g. north pole using stereographic projection). For the cylinder you have to leave one line out (standard cylindrical coordinates would give a bijective parametrization,  but the domain of this parametrization is not all of $ R^2$, in particular it is not open). For the torus you have to leave out two intersecting rings.

My question is basically if it is fruitful to the characterization of manifolds to study the "exceptional sets" that I described above.

Of course, one would first need to answer whether these sets are well defined or if there are significantly different ways to almost-parametrize a manifold. In the latter case, can we fix that by cinsidering the minimally complex exceptional sets in some sense?

I'd be thankful for any insight whatsoever. If any connection to algebraic topology for beginners can be made I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Every manifold (well, essentially every manifold) can be given the structure of a CW complex with a single $n$-cell. Then deleting the interior of that $n$-cell, we get a CW complex of dimension $n-1$. There are topological constraints that say this must be at least reasonably complicated; for instance, its homology agrees with that of the manifold in degree up to $n-1$.

Comment: I probably should have made clear that I actually do not know a bit about algebraic topology. As a corollary, I unfortunately do not understand a bit of what you wrote. Could you dumb it down for me?